# What object do I need to respond to .map(&:key)? (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a code challenge, and know the message I need my code to respond to.
I also know I have the correct data in my object to pass the test, I just can't seem to get the format correct.

The test is

`class.method.map(&:name)`

Which should return an array of names that the method returns.

I have tried having my method return a hash with :name as a key and an array containing the hash but neither work, I'm getting this error

```
rb:82:in `each': undefined method `name' for [:name, "Name I want returned"]:Array
```

What do I need to do to respond to the map call correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class.method.map(&:name)` means

```
class.method.map do |instance|
  instance.name
end
```

So basically your `method` needs to return a enumeration of objects, which has a method named `name`.